# Why does Online Accounts on Ubuntu lose the authorization so often?

Tags: 13.10, online-accounts

I was wondering how I have never had any similar problems with any android or web application that use similar methods of authorization to Facebook, Twitter or Google.

Yet on AskUbuntu there is myriad of questions about Online Accounts needing re-authorizing on services and my own experiences just confirm this behavior.

Is this because buggy code in the Online Accounts itself or services not following API's they have released?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing myself. I don't have this problem with other auth services.